# React select inline options

Tags: react-select

I'm using react-select and I was wondering how I could use the optionRenderer to display my options inline. See the picture below:

[image]

[#react-select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-select)

Comment: which version of react-select are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSX inside label option

```
const options = [
  { 
    label: <div className="label-item">ORA</div>, 
    value="ORA" 
  }, ....
]
```

Then modify class of react-select to customize it (maybe use styled-components)

```
import 'styled' from 'styled-component'
import 'select' from 'react-select'
const StyleSelect = styled(select).`
  .select {
    .select-control { ... } 
  }
`
```

Just use `StyleSelect` like normal `select`